# Track App Store download source

Tags: download, app-store, analytics

Is there a way to track App Store download source ? Per example, if I post a link on the Facebook page of my app, can I know how many person downloaded my app from this link ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can track downloads from devices iOS8+ and tvOS2+ with campaign links from Apple's App Analytics: https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/

Choose your app, then go to "Sources" and create a new link with the link builder there.

It will look like this:

[image]

pt= is your unique provider token; ct= is your campaign name

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this feature ! But my app is available on iOS 7+, so people that use iOS 7 will not appear on App Analytics ?

Comment: Nope that's the only limitation. But iOS7 and lower accounts only for <5% of the iOS users, so I think that should not be a big problem. https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

Comment: It took some poking around for me to find the exact place Max referred to where you can create a campaign link. For those also looking, as of this writing it is: Log into your Apple Developer account. Go to iTunes Connect. Click on App Analytics. Select the app for which you want to make a link. Click on Sources in the top menu. Click on Campaigns just below that. On the right side of the screen, click on "Generate a Campaign Link". You'll then be on the screen to create links.

Comment: @NaguibIhab as far as I know you can use standard UTM tracking parameters: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

Answer (score 3):

Go to App Store Connect -> Analytics -> select the app -> Acquisition -> Campaigns.

Generate URL-s here with the + button.