# Pass app analytics data to app

Tags: swift, app-store, analytics, ads

It's possible to track app conversions through app analytics such as the source of app conversions

[Track App Store download source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114223/track-app-store-download-source)

but is it possible to pass this information through to the app itself? This is possible on android through the Google play store but so far I haven't found any way of doing this on iOS.

What I want to do is pass the source of app conversions (how many conversions are being driven by a given ad) through to the app so I can then insert it into an SQL database.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Anything's possible with a server.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not currently possible.

You can analyze this data in App Analytics within AppStoreConnect, but you cannot access it from your application.